# navigation controller not showing titles for tabs

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

I have created a `navigationController`. In the OnButtonTap action I am adding a `tabBarController` to `navigationController`. Now I want the title of every tab on `navigationItemBar`. But when I change the title in the `viewDidLoad` method of `viewControllers` of tab-bar it won't change.

I tried this in `viewDidLoad` method of view controller in tab bars.

```
self.title = @"Friends";
self.navigationItem.title=@"Friends";
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

and the button is also not hiding...

Comment: Pl. post the code of adding the tab bar controller to navigation controller. 
Also try to change title in ViewWillAppear method..

Comment: set the title and buttons of the tabs where you declare them.like- - (void) setupNavBar
{
    int selectedIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex;
    if(selectedIndex == 0) {
        
        NSLog(@"##  0");
        self.title = @"Select a Destination";
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
        self.navigationItem.titleView = nil;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    }

Comment: add it in viewcontrollers of tabbarcontroller view will apear methods it will like  self.tabbarcontroller.navigationcontroller.navigationitem.title ="" it will change whenever you change tab to navigation controllers title\

Answer (score 0):

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
  self.title=@"YourTitle";
    // Custom initialization
    [self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImage"]withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselectedImage"]];
}
return self;
}
```